# Android Studio Display Image in Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, firebase, imagedownload

I have an image store in the firebase realtime db as a url. I am trying to download the image and display the image in an alert dialog message. When excuting the code the alert dialog appears but no image is displayed.

[image]

ImageDownloader Class:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class ImageDownload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>

{
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewWeakReference;

    public ImageDownload(ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViewWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... string)
    {
        return downloadBitmap(string[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if(isCancelled())
        {
            bitmap = null ;
        }

        ImageView imageView = imageViewWeakReference.get();
        if (imageView != null)
        {
            if (bitmap != null)
            {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url)
    {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try
        {
            URL url1 = new URL(url);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
            int StatusCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            if(StatusCode != connection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                return null;
            }

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            if(inputStream != null)
            {
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(connection != null)
            {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I created a layout xml file for the alert dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
  btVoucher1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                    {
                        String qrcode = dataSnapshot.child("Voucher").child("1").getValue().toString();

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), qrcode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertVoucher1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                        alertVoucher1.setNeutralButton("Close",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                                    {
                                        dialog.cancel();

                                    }
                                });

                        new ImageDownload(qrCodeVoucher).execute(qrcode);
                        AlertDialog voucher = alertVoucher1.create();
                        voucher.show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                    {
                        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Can anyone provide any help? Thank you.

Comment: First check image download is working properly if it will work fine then create a separate layout for AlertDialog.Builder and set that layout to dialog and set image path to image view from that layout file.

Comment: Please share the content of                         String qrcode = dataSnapshot.child("Voucher").child("1").getValue().toString();

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: Plus, try using a definitive width and height of the image view for test. for e.g. 100 x 100

Answer (score 1):

Here I could see you are parallelly loading the image on async task , which may take some time to download the image and before that you have called the alert dialog. So before the image comes up alert is shown.

**Solution** : You can call of alert dialog shown from the postExecute() of asyncTask , that will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

you have created a Layout for that but you didn't use it anywhere I think you are new here whatever you are doing can be done by using a Dialog and Not by using an AlertDialog Here I am giving you an example :

```
            // Create a custom dialog object
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
            // Include dialog.xml file
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialg_layout);
            // Set dialog title
            dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

            // set values for custom dialog components - text, image or button

            ImageView image = dialog.findViewById(R.id.your_imageview_id);
           // image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image0);
```

now, Instead of creating an AsyncTask I suggest you to Use Glide or Picasso (libraries to load URLs in ImageView)
   and You also have to create a dismiss button in your Dialogs Layout

```
            dialog.show();

            Button declineButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.your_dialog_button);
            // if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            declineButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Close dialog
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

happy coding :)